# Microsoft Graph App Authorization Java Standalone Application

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get authorization and access token from Azure Portal to access Microsoft Graph. I have created a simple class called `PublicClient`. I have also given permissions for Microsoft Graph to the Web API that I have created in Azure Portal.

My class:

```
public class PublicClient
{
    private static AuthenticationContext authContext = null;
    private static AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
    private static ExecutorService service = null;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
            String url = "https://login.windows.net/" +
                Authentication_Constants.TENANT + "/oauth2/token/";

            authContext = new AuthenticationContext(url, true, service);

            ClientCredential clientCred =
                new ClientCredential(Authentication_Constants.CLIENTID,
                    Authentication_Constants.SECRET);

            Future<AuthenticationResult> future =
                authContext.acquireToken(Authentication_Constants.RESOURCE,
                    clientCred, null);

            authResult = future.get();
            System.out.println(authResult.getAccessToken());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
8137 [pool-1-thread-1] 
ERROR adal4jPii.class com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext - \
[Correlation ID: 946dff2f-2451-407d-8124-8a1be543bca5] Request to acquire token failed.
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: access_denied
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
```

I tried searching a lot but there is no explanation for the error.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: That's an SSL exception. Something is going wrong with the handshake.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? Looks like AAD supports TLS 1.0/1.1/1.2 but not SSL.

Comment: @juunas Java 8.

Comment: That should support TLS just fine then. Not sure but there could be a problem with ADAL. Which version are you using?

Comment: @juunas adal4 I am using

Comment: Actually the library is called Adal4J, read as adal-for-J(ava). The latest version seems to be 1.4.0 :)

Comment: @juunas also its saying access denied. Is it related to some access related issues? even though i have given relevant microsoft graph permissions.

Comment: The exception seems to be saying it's a problem with SSL/TLS, but it doesn't hurt to be thorough. Can you check you have also *granted* the permissions by hitting the Grant Permissions button there where required permissions are defined?

Comment: @juunas I am getting something like this "This application requires application permissions to another application. Consent for application permissions can only be performed by an administrator. Sign out and sign in as an administrator or contact one of your organization's administrators."

Comment: Are you an admin? :)

Comment: App permission grant requires an admin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164854/discussion-between-pranay-wankhede-and-juunas).

Comment: @juunas even after granting permissions...the code throws the same exception!!

Comment: @juunas also i have created web app in azure... not native application... is that problem?

Comment: @juunas its a proxy issue...i connected to the guest account of my organization and it works fine!!! sorry for trouble..its SSL finally!!!

Comment: Heh so the error was correct after all :) You can self-answer the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Whole issue is because of proxy and not anything related to permissions. Still make sure you are able to grant permission to the web app that you have created.But if everything is fine then all pointers points to it being a networking issue.